# Lealeft. Cannot slide an INPUT RANGE over the map DIV

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jquery, events

I've got a control over the leaflet map div:

```
<div id="map">
    <div  style="z-index:9999; position: absolute; bottom:35px;left:10px;  id="divOpacity">
    Opacity
    <input type="range" style="width:80px" min="0" max="100" id="opacity_slider" name="opacity" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this input range control to change the opacity of an imageOverview.

The problem is that when I try to drag the opacity, the map starts panning, and the range control do not move. The only way I can change the range value is to click on a specific point in the range and it changes without problem.

On a mobile device the problem is that there is no way to slide or click to change the range value. How can I prevent this behaviour and let the input range work also if over the leaflet map?

This is the code behind the :

```
$('#opacity_slider').on("change mousemove", function(e) {
     var newval=$(this).val();
     overlay.setOpacity(newval/100);
     L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(this);
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

The `e.preventDefault()` and `L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(this);` don't seem to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this match what you're looking for?
https://consbio.github.io/Leaflet.Range/

Comment: Starting from your suggestion, I used this plugin: https://github.com/Eclipse1979/leaflet-slider